# Changing multiple Dash charts series colors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

i have graph that it has multiple choice on 'Cell' dropdown. by choosing every cell, a new graph draws but they all have same colors. i want that each cell or each graph has its own color.how can i do it? how can i chose graph colors what i want : different graphs with different colors.
the problem is when i choose multiple cells to draw graph for each cell, it shows all of the graphs with just one color

**i have e different dropdowns , and i want when user select different "CELL" s, DRAW A NEW LINE FOR EACH CELL WITH DIFFERENT COLORS. it draws lines , but all of the cells color are the same. it drives me crazy an i dont know what i sthe problem.**

**python codes**

```
excelPath= r'C:\Users\tools\t1\materials-python-dash\avocado_analytics_3\diagram_syria.xlsx'


data = (
  pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelPath), engine='openpyxl' )

  .assign(Date=lambda data: pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], format="%m-%d-%Y"))
  .sort_values(by="Date" )
 )
  regions = data["region"].sort_values().unique()
 kashef_types = data["type"].sort_values().unique()

 external_stylesheets = [
 {
    "href": (
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?"
    "family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap"
   ),
   "rel": "stylesheet",
  },
  ]
  app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
  app.title = "KASHEF Analytics: Understand Your Interference!"

   app.layout = html.Div(
 children=[
    html.Div(
       children=[
           # 
            html.P(children="K", className="myz"),
          html.H1(
              children="KASHEF Analytics", className="header-title"
            ),
          html.P(
             children=(
                "Analyze the behavior of Cells "
                " over the different times "
             ),
              className="header-description",
          ),
      ],
      className="header",
   ),
   html.Div(
       children=[
           html.Div(
              children=[
                  html.Div(children="Cell", className="menu-title"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                      id="region-filter",
                       options=[
                          {     "label": region,
                                "value": region
                           }
                         for region in regions
                      ],
                      value="Banias-Qouz_L1",
                      clearable=False,
                      searchable=True,

                    className="dropdown",
                ),
            ]
         ), 
         html.Div(
             children=[
                 html.Div(children="Type", className="menu-title"),
                 dcc.Dropdown(
                     id="type-filter",
                     options=[
                        {
                            "label": kashef_type.title(),
                            "value": kashef_type,
                        }
                        for kashef_type in kashef_types
                    ],
                    value="organic",
                    clearable=False,
                    searchable=False,
                    className="dropdown",
                ),
            ],
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children="Date Range", className="menu-title"
                ),
                dcc.DatePickerRange(
                    id="date-range",
                    min_date_allowed=data["Date"].min().date(),
                    max_date_allowed=data["Date"].max().date(),
                    start_date=data["Date"].min().date(),
                    end_date=data["Date"].max().date(),
                ),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    className="menu",
   ),
   html.Div(
       children=[
          html.Div(
             children=dcc.Graph(
                id="price-chart",
                config={"displayModeBar": False},
            ),
            className="card",
        ),
        #html.Div(
        #3    children=dcc.Graph(
        #        id="price-chart",
         #       config={"displayModeBar": False},
          #  ),
           # className="card",
       # ),
     ],
     className="wrapper",
    ),
    ]
   )


   


    @app.callback(
    Output("price-chart", "figure"),
    Input("region-filter", "value"),
    Input("type-filter", "value"),
    Input("date-range", "start_date"),
    Input("date-range", "end_date"),
 )
 def update_charts(region, kashef_type, start_date, end_date):
 filtered_data = data.query(
 "region == @region and type == @kashef_type"
 " and Date >= @start_date and Date <= @end_date"
   )
  pucch_pusch_chart_figure = {
   "data": [
     {
        "x": filtered_data["Date"],
        "y": filtered_data["PUCCH"],
        "type": "lines",
        "hovertemplate": "%{y:.2f}<extra></extra>",
    },
  ],
   "layout": {
    "title": {
        "text": "Analyzed by Kashef",
        "x": 0.05,
        "xanchor": "left",
    },
    "xaxis": {"fixedrange": True},
    "yaxis": {"tickprefix": "", "fixedrange": True},
    "colorway": ["#17B897"],
   },
  }
  return pucch_pusch_chart_figure

   if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='172.27.112.57',port='8050',debug=True)
```

**CSS Code**

```
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
 }

.header {
  /*TOP BACKGROUND*/
   background-color: #081054;
   height: 288px;
    padding: 16px 0 0 0;
 }

 .header-emoji {



   font-size: 48px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;

   }

 .header-title {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }

  .header-description {
     color: #FFFFFF;
      margin: 4px auto;
      text-align: center;
       max-width: 384px;
  }

  .wrapper {
       margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1024px;
        padding-right: 10px;
         padding-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 32px;
    }

   .card {
       margin-bottom: 24px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
 }

  .menu {
     height: 112px;
     width: 912px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-evenly;
     padding-top: 24px;
     margin: -80px auto 0 auto;
     background-color: #DEEAFD;
     box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
   }

   .Select-control {
       width: 256px;
        height: 48px;
      } 

   .Select--single>.Select-control .Select-value,
   .Select-placeholder {
   line-height: 48px;
   }

  .Select--multi .Select-value-label {
   line-height: 32px;
   }

.menu-title {
   margin-bottom: 6px;
   font-weight: bold;
    color: #081054;
   }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @EricLavault the link you wrote is not an answer , it is also a question

Comment: Yes sorry these comments are automatically written by SO when users flag duplicate questions (even if they have no answer..), which I did. Please don't ask the same question twice, edit your original post and delete this one, or delete the original post. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: I added an answer but haven't tested it because we can't access your data. NB: Next time, or if the answer doesn't work, please provide a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (ie. with sample data), think about people that want to help here, if we copy/paste your code it should lead to the same result as yours, if it leads to an error or more generally if the problem is not reproducible, we skip the question. And this is the main reason you didn't get any answer until now, although the problem is trivial for experienced plotly users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`px.line()`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line) from plotly.express to obtain the desired behavior :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("price-chart", "figure"),
    Input("region-filter", "value"),
    Input("type-filter", "value"),
    Input("date-range", "start_date"),
    Input("date-range", "end_date"),
)
def update_charts(region, kashef_type, start_date, end_date):
    filtered_data = data.query(
        "region == @region and type == @kashef_type"
        " and Date >= @start_date and Date <= @end_date"
    )

    pucch_pusch_chart_figure = px.line(
        filtered_data,
        x="Date",
        y="PUCCH",
        color="region"
    )

    pucch_pusch_chart_figure.update_traces(hovertemplate="%{y:.2f}<extra></extra>")

    pucch_pusch_chart_figure.update_layout(
        title={
            "text": "Analyzed by Kashef",
            "x": 0.05,
            "xanchor": "left",
        }
        xaxis_fixedrange=True,
        yaxis_fixedrange=True,
        yaxis_tickprefix=""
    )

    return pucch_pusch_chart_figure
```

See [Line Plots with column encoding color](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-plots-with-column-encoding-color).